# How to migrate categories from Magento 1.9.1 to 1.9.4? Also - Will EXPORT of products and customers work?

Tags: import, migration, export, importexport

```
Magento 1.9.1 to Magento 1.9.4
```

We are setting up again and I can't figure out how to migrate categories from our old (live) Magento 1.9.1 site to the new 1.9.4? Is there a way to do that?

I will also want to export and import PRODUCTS and CUSTOMERS. **Will the:**

```
System --) Import/Export --) Export
```

**work?**

Comment: why don't you just try it on a local or staging magento 1.9.4 instance?

Comment: I will try it - it's just I didn't see an option to migrate categories over. Is that possible?

Comment: categories will be created on product import